# Scala.js Source Map Debug Breakpoints Disabled in Browser

Tags: scala.js

I'm attempting to debug my scala.js application in the chrome browser and I can't seem to get any breakpoints to work.

[image]

Does anyone know how to enable the breakpoints?

Comment: Did you enable source maps in the Chrome options? They're not on by default.

Comment: Enable javascript source maps is checked on in my chrome browser.  I have noticed this happens with typescript also so I'm sure it's a chrome thing.